# How to link a ".so" library in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: linker, .a, vs-android

I was wondering if anyone knew how to link a .so dynamic library (or a .a  static library for that mater) in Microsoft visual studio. The following steps have not worked for either .a or .so.

I'm playing around with the vs-android plugging to develop in Android NDK using MVS and I'm trying to add a custom library, compiled as a .so, to the project.

1 - I've created a dynamic library (.so) project alongside one of the sample projects (the san-angeles project), in the same solution.

2 - I've set the .so project, let's call it "engine" as a dependency of san-angeles. The engine.so file is generated without any problems, and appears in the {SolutionFolder?}/Android/Debug folder.

3 - I've added engine.so to the linker additional includes of san-angeles and the {SolutionFolder?}/Android/Debug folder (as a full path, something like C:/projects/.../Debug) to the additional linker directories.

But when I compile san-angeles I get the error:

"arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe: engine.so: No such file or directory"

So I'm guessing I need to do something else to add a .so/.a to a project? Maybe change the name to libengine.so or something like that? A lot of the default includes have the lib prefix, so I don't know if it's something along those lines.

Thank you for the help, 
Jaime

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, so in my case this was solved by:

1 - Naming the generated engine.a as libengine.a

2 - Instead of, from MVS, adding engine.a to Preferences/Linker/Additional Dependencies, I added to Preferences/Linker/Command Line -l"engine"

With this, the project finally managed to find and engine.a

Hope this helps someone else. :)

Comment: Your question involved using an .so but your answer used .a - did you ever manage to link in an .so?

Comment: No, sorry, once it got working with a .a I didn't bother pushing it.

Comment: I am having the same issue and unfortunately your suggested fix does not help, still get the error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error MSB6006 "clang.exe" exited with code 1. Android2.NativeActivity
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Application Type\Android\3.0\Android.Common.targets 119

What does work however is when i add the .so/.a lib directly in the solution explorer.

Although this seems to work it is still less than ideal for multi architecture builds.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anybody stumbling on this problem:

1. Add the directory where the `.so` resides in `Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories`. The project you are compiling must be also a `Dynamic Library .so` for the linker to be available. This appends the `-L` flag to the commandline
2. In the `Linker -> Command Line` append your `.so` to the `Additional Options` with the `-l` flag with quotes, e.g. `-l"MyDynamicLibraryWithoutLibPrefixAndExtension"`. In my case I wanted to link `libassimp.so` -> `-l"assimp"`